# CSS Menu Recreation

Tags: html, css

I have been given the task of recreating the following menu:

[image]

What would be the best way to set the line underneath `border-bottom`? and then have the image on hover/active?

The gray line you see in the image is the bottom of my bookmarks bar.  My header has a height of `50px`

How would I make my nav have the correct distance above like in the image below - using `bottom:0`?

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    <h1><img src="_assets/images/b_logoheadertab.png" width="250" height="50" alt="B Logoheadertab"></h1>
        <nav class="main">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
            <div class="login">
                <p>Welcome <a class="link">UserName</a> | <a class="logOutLink" href="#">Log Out</a></p>
    </header>
```

**CSS:**

```
header{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#184C82;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
header h1{
    float:left;
    width:250px
}
header nav{
    float:left;
    margin:0 15px 0 0;
    color:#fff;
    width:434px;
    height:50px;
}
header nav ul li{
    display:inline;
    margin:0 0 0 2px;
}
header nav li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    height:100px;
    width:45px;
}
header nav li{
    width:45px;
    background:url('../images/nav_active.png') no-repeat;
}
header .login{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: @RohitAzad bulletinmessenger.net

Comment: For SEO reasons you shouldn't make an image menu, especially not one where the actual images are set as background, you can't pass relevant meta information off to the crawlers this way. You will not gain much ranking the way you're set it up now. Ideally you should switch to text for the actual text in the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header nav ul li {
 display:inline;
 margin:0 0 0 2px;
 line-height:50px;     
 padding-bottom: 10px; // additional space for border bottom and arrow
}

header nav li:hover, header nav li.active {    
 background:url('http://www.ptt.co.uk/img/RedUpArrow.gif') no-repeat center bottom; // center it and place it to the bottom 
 border-bottom: 1px solid white; // for border bottom
}
```

For active class

```
<nav class="main">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Messenger</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Campaigner</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Connet API</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

I think it is just what you need

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/xqDtM/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Hey now you can define

in your css

```
.appsuite ul li:hover{
background:url('yourarrow.png') no-repeat xxpx xxpx; // define position according to your layout 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what is the hight of the ul and li in the above issue? as I cannot seem to get the distances correct.

Comment: I think you don't define height .